# Parse Push notification not working if app is killed (Android)

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I have implemented Parse notification in my app. I have put the initialization call in the app.onCreate().

When the app is running, it works perfectly. However, if the app is killed, I find that the notifications are not coming through.

Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0):

If the app is force stopped, Google Cloud Messaging won't work until the app is launched again by the user. That's the behavior since Android 3+ (don't remember the exact version).

If the app runs in the background or is stopped implicitly by the OS (to free memory), GCM will work.

Parse push notifications would behave the same, since they use GCM.